# what is meant by this error "No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup" in mongodb?

Tags: windows, mongodb, mongoose

we edited mongod.cfg file for binding server ip address, after editing file mongodb service has stopped functioning, so we thought may service might have got corrupted after edit, so we have deleted the service using `sc.exe`. Now when we are trying to install mongodb as service it is giving below error-

Command used to install again
`mongod --install`

Error-

`2020-05-07T17:14:55.755+0530 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2020-05-07T17:14:55.762+0530 W  ASIO     [main] No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup
2020-05-07T17:14:55.763+0530 I  CONTROL  [main] --install has to be used with a log file for server output`

Unable to understand what this error is trying to say, and how do we install the mongodb service back with proper IP binding.

Please let me know if any further details required, have also searched on google and SO, but didn't got the solution
Kindly help to sought this issue-

Comment: This messages are with only  I(nformation) and W(arning) severity , they do not indicate possible cause why service is not starting ... ,  you can try running from the cmd to check if it starts correctly with the modified cfg file :mongod.exe --config “C:\where_the_cfg_is_located\mongod.cfg”   , check similar issue here: https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongodb-wont-start-as-a-windows-service-but-will-start-at-the-command-line/2174

Answer (score 0):

Set the database service to startup using the NetworkService account in Windows, which I think was the default as part of the installation process. Now change this to use the Local System account option and the service now starts and works without any problems.

Path to change things:
Press Cmd+R keys to bring up start menu
Type services and run the app
Locate MongoDB Server, right-click and select Properties
Access LogOn tab
Select Local System account radio button
Select OK